# Messenger bot send a message every 5th message

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, bots, messenger

I am making a simple bot for messenger on python using fbmq, that handles quick questions.

I made bot to send a message when users text to my Facebook page out of my working hours.

```
working_hours = [12,13,14,15,16]

if messaging_event.get('message') and (now.hour no in working_hours):
   page.send(sender_id, "Sorry we are closed!"
```

Since people normally express what they want in more than 1 message, they got their chat spammed with "We are closed message!"

I didn't like that that much, because I want to give a chance for user to leave a message so I can answer tomorrow.

Do you know any way I can make bot send "We are closed!" every 5th message sent by the user?

I tried this:

```
count = 0
if (count / 3 == 1):
  page.send(sender_id, "Sorry we are closed!")
  count = 0
if messaging_event.get('message') and (now.hour no in working_hours):
  count += 1
```

But it didn't work. If you have any ideas how can I realize that I will be really thankful :)

// I tried a while loop.

```
for messaging_event in messaging:

        sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
        recipient_id = messaging_event['recipient']['id']

        messaging_event.get('postback'):
        messaging_event.get('message'):

        while (now.hour not in working_hours):
            count = 0
            if (count/3 == 1):
                page.send(sender_id, "Hello")

            if messaging_event.get('message'):
                count += 1
```

But it didn't work. Recieved an error by Facebook deliviring messages to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't find a better solution for this.

```
count = 0
working_hours = [ 8... ]

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    print(request.data)
    data = request.get_json()

    if data['object'] == "page":
        entries = data['entry']

        for entry in entries:
            messaging = entry['messaging']

            for messaging_event in messaging:

                sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
                recipient_id = messaging_event['recipient']['id']

                if now.hour not in working_hours:
                    global count
                if (count == 3):
                    page.send(sender_id, "We are closed!")
                if (count == 4):
                    count = 0
                if messaging_event['message'].get('text'):
                    count += 1
```

I would want to make it with timestamp now, but honestly don't know how. So for example if there is a user you didn't text anything for a long time would receive a "Welcome back, we missed you" message.

I am not sure how this code will work with people texting at the same time neither. Probably all buggy, since I use a global variable. If you have any ideas please help :)